# Using words in other languages

Tags: creative-writing, language

I would like to use a few words from different languages but I am not sure on how to handle the fact that the words are read one way in English and sound totally different in their original language?

Comment: Is this a work of fiction? Do you think pronunciation is important to the story?

Comment: Why is the sound of the words of importance to you? Will you be using them in a context where their pronunciation is going to have a role in the plot (e.g. used in a pun, rhyme, or a scene where a characters(mis)pronounces some of them). If you plan none of this, the way the readers pronounce them will not matter - even if they do not know the source language and mess up the sounds.

Comment: Yes it is fiction. I guess it could be that I put to much thought into it but I liked the idea of linking our reality into my fiction world. The connection between the two is a major part of the story and I felt like using the proper pronunciation was another way to solidify the connection.

Comment: If your other language is non-Latin, you are in luck (sort of), because you just use English transliteration. But if this is a language with Latin script, you need to do a lot of extra work (in a fiction book, in non-fiction it's Ok to use [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)) to convey the pronunciation. "Paris" is spoken very differently in English and French, but there is nothing usually done about it.

Comment: Okay thank you! It probably just ment more to me then it ever would a reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a memoir of my years in the Holy Land and had to use Hebrew often (and occasionally Arabic). I simply used a transliteration in English and put translit. in brackets. Where I used the Hebrew script I put an annotation at the end of the chapter.